# Open Pull Request from Enterprise Github in Visual Studio Code Dev Containers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying Dev Containers in Visual Studio code.

I use an enterprise Github (github.company.com)
When i try the **Clone Github Pull Request in Dev Container** option, i can not enter the pull request form the enterprise github. the Visual Studio code is only accepting urls for github.com

Is there any way to open the Pull Requests form enterprise github in Dev Containers ?

Thanks